# Learn Webservice with SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-services

I need to learn about webservice in relation to SharePoint and what page, material etc can you recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 expose many REST web service, you can find more information on [SharePoint 2013 Web Services library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193051.aspx), and you can see this page to [Get started with the SharePoint 2013 REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380.aspx)

Also you can read this book [**Microsoft SharePoint 2013 App Development**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145371805.do) that explain  Working with the REST API

[image]